# How to move file inside directory, using Linux (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mv, ash

I'm looking for a good shell one liner to move or rename a file inside a directory, where the target and destination parent directories are the same, and different than the current working directory.  For example, the thing I don't want to write:

```
$ mv /usr/share/nginx/html/app.xml /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

How can I do this same thing without typing '/usr/share/nginx/html/' twice or using multiple commands (to switch directory, pushd, etc)?

Comment: My favorite part is that I was accidentally moving the wrong file here (.xml to .html, wtf?) but nobody cared and they just answered appropriately :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [braces expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BRACEEXPREF):

```
$ mv /usr/share/nginx/html/{app.xml,index.html}
```

Comment: Part of the `parameter expansion` is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), but this syntax doesn't seems to be POSIX

Comment: [brace expansion is Bash only](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion#portability)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subshell:

```
(cd /usr/share/nginx/html; mv app.xml index.html)
```